# Toto Aquia II fill valve squeaks after cleaning

Tags: toilet

After cleaning the fill valve (using this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8k7OyAtLj3U)) from deposits it's making a loud squeaking noise when the water "levels out" after a flush. What could it be? I understand it's some internal mechanism that stop the water filling after it reaches a level.

Answer (score 1):

There is tiny particulate in the valve which may be partnered with wear that makes the valve vibrate and squeak or squeal.

You can fight this problem for a long time, or just change the fill valve. They are not that expensive and probably will take less time than cleaning the valve multiple times, only to have the squeak return.